# Concurrent saving in background with MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

For testing purpose i have the following code which called from main thread (in `viewDidLoad` method).

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext * _Nonnull localContext) {
        [FieldDescription MR_createEntityInContext:localContext];
    } completion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!contextDidSave) {
            DDLogError(@"Error saving field description: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];
}
```

In a result, a part of entities saving is completed with `contextDidSave == YES`, but other isn't because result is `contextDidSave == NO && error == nil`. For those entities i get the following message from MagicalRecord in logs:
`NO CHANGES IN ** MagicalRecord Root Saving Context ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING`

Why i can't do such things with MagicalRecord, what i'm missing?

I know that if i place all of 50 those calls inside `saveWithBlock` it will work, but my current architecture won't allow me this because i'm making a lot of magicalRecord calls from asynchronously operations.

UPD:
When testing more, i found that all entities was eventually saved in storage, despite of half of `MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:` operations were completed with `contextDidSave == NO` and `error == nil` result. Anyway, i can't rely on such result of saving operation to make my system reliable.

What i'm missing and how can i make this works without such odd behaviour?

Comment: But i'm creating a record -> new record -> there is a change in context.

Comment: When creating an entity, it first checks if that entity already exists. If it does (based on the entity's attributes set in the userInfo relationship and primaryKey), it will NOT save. Also, are you sure you want to be calling `MagicalRecord` save with block 50 times? Shouldn't that for loop be inside the save block and create 50 entities in the same context?

Comment: Yes it definitely should be placed inside the save block, but i can't do that because of my project architecture. In future i will refact it, but now i have the situation when `MagicalRecord saveWithblock` is calling several times simultaneously.

Comment: I can't get it: how can entity which i'm creating just now already exists?